# NSInteger and int type warnings seem inconsistent

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5

I'm getting type error warnings in one program and not the other, yet the code looks the same to me.

First, as new to Obj C/IOS I thought I was supposed to use NSInteger rather than int.

Here's what does work; (Code from the Stanford 193P course that shows me no warnings)

(I have tried to show just excerpts to keep it simple.)

CardMatchingGame.m

```
@interface CardMatchingGame()
property (nonatomic, readwrite) NSInteger score;
...
```

CardGameViewController.m

```
interface CardGameViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *resultsSlider;
```

....

```
self.scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Score: %d", self.game.score];
....
int sliderValue = lroundf(self.resultsSlider.value);
```

Here's my code modeled on it for a different game.  It looks the same to me but I get type onversion warnings:

BullsEyeGame.m

```
@interface BullsEyeGame ()

@property (nonatomic, readwrite) NSInteger score;

....
```

ViewController.m

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *sliderValue;

....

self.scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", self.game.score]; //NSInteger should not be used as format aguments; add an explicit cast to unsigned long.

int slider = lroundf(self.sliderValue.value); //Implicit conversion warning here
```

What am I missing here?

Where is the key hole in my understanding?

Comment: Perhaps the 1st isn't supporting arm64 and the 2nd is. Or the 2nd project has more warnings enabled.

Comment: Also, try cleaning and rebuilding and you might see some warnings pop up that had been "forgotten/ignored".

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer the core question of why the two programs behave differently, but i fixed my warnings by:

1. Changing lroundf() to round()
2. Changing the format specifier from %d to %ld.

Answer (score 0):

In the first code sample, you define score with property (in the .m file), but in the second you use @property.  If this isn't a typo, that is the difference between the two programs.

Also, the difference could depend on how you assign a value to the score variable.  Check that area for differences also.

Comment: Thanks. The first was a typo.